# Sh,Bash - When to use -o and when to use ||?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

When I wrote a program in Bash it only worked when I used `||` instead of `-o`. When is it appropriate to use `-o`? Is it only in `sh`?

Comment: Rule of thumb is to never use`-o` or `-a` in `test` expressions because their behavior is not well defined.

Comment: The *only* time you'd use `-o` is inside a `[ ]` or `test` expression, but you shouldn't even use it there. See [BashFAQ #31: "What is the difference between `test`, `[` and `[[` ?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) (especially the "Feature" table). [This Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs/306141#306141) may also help.

Comment: I don't think I have ever used `-o`. Can you give an example where you would use it, and why?

Comment: @user1934428 From iBug's answer: `[ -e 1.txt -o -e 2.txt ]` would test whether either `1.txt` or `2.txt` exists. But since `-o` can sometimes be syntactically ambiguous, `[ -e 1.txt ] || [ -e 2.txt ]` is generally preferred.

Answer (score 1):

`-o` is an operator for the command `[` (or `test` - they're equivalent except `[` must be closed with a `]`).

`||` is for joining two commands, executing the latter only if the former failed with a non-zero exit code.

This is what you would write:

```
[ -e 1.txt -o -e 2.txt ]       # if either file exists
[ -e 1.txt ] || [ -e 2.txt ]   # same effect using 2 commands
test -e 1.txt -o -e 2.txt
test -e 1.txt || test -e 2.txt
```

However, `||` can be used to chain arbitrary commands, not just `test`:

```
nginx -tq || echo "Bad nginx config"
```

Comment: `||` is also used inside a double-bracket conditional expression, e.g. `[[ -e 1.txt || -e 2.txt ]]`. `[[ ]]` expressions are similar to `[ ]` tests, but with cleaner syntax (the downside: they're not as portable to other shells).